# How to loop through aara and append each value to div with specific class

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with data which I want to append to some divs which have the same class but for some reason I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

Here is the code:

```
var data = [ 
  { "country" : "Germany", "capital" : "Berlin"}, 
  { "country" : "Sweden", "capital" : "Stockholm"}, 
  { "country" : "Italy", "capital" : "Rome"}, 
  { "country" : "Japan", "capital" : "Tokyo"}, 
  { "country" : "USA", "capital" : "Washington DC"} 
];

let countries = data;

let capitalwrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.capital') 
for (var j = 0; j < countries.length; j++){
  capitalwrapper.forEach(function(elem) {
  let capital = countries[j].capital;
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  elem.innerHTML = capital;
})

}
```

At this point, Washington DC gets displayed in all elements but I don't knwo why.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/moa16brs/23/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what your code is doing, you are looping through all countries, and for each of those countries you are looping through all divs, setting the `innerHTML` of the current div to each capital one after another.

Instead you should only use one loop, that loops through both collections only once:

```js
var data = [ { "country" : "Germany", "capital" : "Berlin"}, { "country" : "Sweden", "capital" : "Stockholm"}, { "country" : "Italy", "capital" : "Rome"}, { "country" : "Japan", "capital" : "Tokyo"}, { "country" : "USA", "capital" : "Washington DC"} ];

let countries = data;

let capitalwrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.capital') 
for (var j = 0; j < countries.length; j++){
  let capital = countries[j].capital;
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = capital;
  capitalwrapper[j].append(span); // only add the span to the current div
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="country">
   <span class="name"></span>
   <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="country">
   <span class="name"></span>
   <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="country">
   <span class="name"></span>
   <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="country">
   <span class="name"></span>
   <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="country">
   <span class="name"></span>
   <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>  
  
  //other content
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.

Comment: Een though I get `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined` @LucaKiebel

Comment: Make sure that both collections have the same size. If you have fewer div than countries, you are bound to get errors here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you iterate over all capitals names, and inside it do a forEach which will always call the function, so the function will last be called with the last capital, and all spans will be the same.

```
let countries = data;

let capitalwrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.capital') 
for (var j = 0; j < countries.length; j++){
    let elem = capitalwrapper[j];
    let capital = countries[j].capital;
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    elem.innerHTML = capital;   
}
```

This code fixes that, but it relies on having as many `span.capital` as capitals in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop your data and select the `.capital` elements with the same index.

```js
var data = [ { "country" : "Germany", "capital" : "Berlin"}, { "country" : "Sweden", "capital" : "Stockholm"}, { "country" : "Italy", "capital" : "Rome"}, { "country" : "Japan", "capital" : "Tokyo"}, { "country" : "USA", "capital" : "Washington DC"} ];

let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.capital') 

data.forEach(({capital}, i) => {
  divs[i].innerHTML = capital
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="country">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="country">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="country">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="country">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="country">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="capital"></span>
  </div>

  //other content
</div>
```